# PHP - Multi Curl - scraping for data/content

Tags: php, dom, xpath, curl, web-scraping

I have started building a single Curl session with - curl, dom, xpath, and it worked great.

I am now building a scraper based off curl for taking data off multiple sites in one flow, and the script is echo'ing the single phrase i put in.. but it does not pick up variables.

```
do{
    $n=curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
}while ($active);

foreach ($urls as $i => $url){  
    $res[$i]=curl_multi_getcontent($conn[$i]);      
    echo ('<br />success');
}
```

So this does echo the success-text as many times as there are urls.. but really this is not what i want.. I want to break up the html like i could with the single curl session..

What i did in the single curl session:

```
//parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($res);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);         
$product_img = $xpath->query("//div[@id='MAIN']//a");

for ($i = 0; i < $product_img->length; $i++){
    $href = $product_img->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />Link : $url";
}
```

This dom parsing / xpath is working for the single session curl, but not when i run the multicurl.
On Multicurl i can do curl_multi_getcontent for the URL from the session, but this is not want..
I would like to get the same content as i picked up with Dom / Xpath in the single session.
What can i do ?

**EDIT**

It seems i am having problems with the getAttribute. It is a link for an image i am having trouble grabbing. The link is showing when scraping, but then it throws an error :

*Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in*

The query:

```
// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$product_img = $xpath->query("//img[@class='product']");
$product_name = $xpath->query("//img[@class='product']");
```

This is working:

```
for ($i = 0; i < $product_name->length; $i++) {
    $prod_name = $product_name->item($i);
    $name = $prod_name->getAttribute('alt');
    echo "<br />Link stored:  $name";
}
```

This is not working:

```
for ($i = 0; i < $product_img->length; $i++) {
    $href = $product_img->item($i);
    $pic_link = $href->getAttribute('src');
    echo "<br />Link stored:  $pic_link";
}
```

Any idea of what i am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us read the question more easily, please format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, it is only that one `src` that won't work right.
This question can be considered "solved".

Comment: For some odd reason it is only that one 'src' that won't work right.. So this can be considered "solved". /Niels